# Android addRule RelativeLayout.BELOW not render correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-view

I want to dynamically inflate a RelativeLayout based on number of cards. For testing purpose I set the loop to 3. But when I run the code, I can only view the last 2 cards, not 3. What I'm missing here?

Kindly find below screenshot and codes.

[image: screenshot]

**fragment_wallet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash1_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- ViewPager -->
    <!-- Navigation -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/wallet_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <include layout="@layout/wallet_dot" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallet_card_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**wallet_card.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wallet_card_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_corner" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallet_card_card_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/card_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wallet_card_txtDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="5m"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallet_card_location_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wallet_card_txtDistance"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/card_view_location_point" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wallet);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout insertPoint = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wallet_card_wrapper);
        List views = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.wallet_card, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.wallet_card_txtDistance);
            textView.setText("10" + i + "m");
            int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources()
                            .getDisplayMetrics());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId()); //<---- I THINK THE PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE
            lp.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
            view.setLayoutParams(lp);

            views.add(view);
        }

        System.out.println(views.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
            insertPoint.addView((View) views.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an ugly fix, but I've googled for 4 hours and can't find a working solution, so it's time for ugly fixes.

First and second elements get overlapped. For some reason, second element is not put below first element. The same code does however put third element below the second one. So, ugly fix is: Add a fake first element which will overlap with your real first element.

It REALLY sucks. But I couldn't find anything else that works.

PS: You probably shouldn't mark this as the correct answer, even if it makes your code work. At least I don't see it as a real answer, just an ugly patch.

Comment: as far as I can tell android's API is damn ugly, so this might well be the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You are right on the line :

in :

```
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId()); 
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You tell the view to be below itsef (by passing its own id in the addRule method)

I would try something like :

```
 int lastId = -1;
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.wallet_card, null);
       ... 
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);

       if(lastId >-1) 
           lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);  //giving the previous view's id here
       lp.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
       view.setLayoutParams(lp);

       views.add(view);

       lastId = view.getId(); //keep this view id for next iteration
 }
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT :**

also remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

it will break the 'below' rule  since it can't be both **align on parent top** and **below the previous view**.

instead use `android:layout_gravity="top"` on the parent relative layout so the first view will be align on parent top. ( is there a reason why it was `gravity:bottom` ?)

Comment: tried with the new code, same result. 2 views. previously, if i dont use gravity:bottom, the RelativeLayout will sit on top of viewpager

Comment: I see,  you have several isues with this layout and even if You could do  it with relative layouts, I think using LinearLayout is better for your needs. As Haresh showed.

Comment: by using LinearLayout my viewpager indicator not working correctly.

Comment: Then I would advise to use linearLayout and to ask a new question with this new issue if you can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

**fragment_wallet.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/wallet_viewPager"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="130dp" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallet_card_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wallet);
    LinearLayout insertPoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wallet_card_wrapper);
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.wallet_card, null, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wallet_card_txtDistance);
        textView.setText("10" + i + "m");
        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
        lp.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 0);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        views.add(view);
    }

    System.out.println(views.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
        insertPoint.addView(views.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: working if using LinearLayout. Why not working with RelativeLayout?